# Hide parent div by class name

Tags: jquery

I have HTML looks like:

```
<div class="group_box">
  <div>
     <div>
       ... <!-- I don't know haw many div's here -- >
       <a class="mark_as_read" ...>
     </div>
  </div>
<div>

....

<div class="group_box">
  <div>
     <div>
       ... <!-- I don't know haw many div's here -- >
       <a class="mark_as_read" ...>
     </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

I want to hide parent "group_box" when user click on "mark_as_read".

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function() {
    $('.mark_as_read_link').bind('click', function() {
      alert($(self));
      $(self).parent('.group_box').hide();
      return false;
    });
 });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. I have not idea what is $(this) in this case....

Comment: `console.log()` to the rescue. You could put `console.log( $(this) );` for example inside the click event, and developer tools console would show you which item was clicked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `.parent()` you can use the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method, which will traverse up the DOM until it finds an element that match the selector.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $().ready(function() {
    $('.mark_as_read_link').on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('.group_box').hide();
      return false;
    });
 });
</script>
```

In the example I use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.bind()`. As of jQuery 1.7, `.bind()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()` for attaching event listeners.

**Update:**

As Joonas points out in his comment, it would be possible to use the `.parents()` method, instead of `.closest()` as suggested above. The difference is that `.parents()` will keep traversing up the DOM, even if it encounter an element that matches the selector, while `.closest()` will stop traversing as soon as it finds a match. In this case I believe `.closest()` is more suited for the purpose, but if you consider using `.parents()` instead, here are the differences, stated in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

**.closest()**

- Begins with the current element
- Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
- The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each element in the original set

**.parents()**

- Begins with the parent element
- Travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied
- The returned jQuery object contains zero or more elements for each element in the original set

Comment: @Joonas Yes, that is correct. However, `.parents()` traverses up the DOM until it reaches the root element, even if it find an element that matches the selector earlier. In this case, I don't think that would be the desired behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use jQuery function `closest()`. It returns the closest parent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mark_as_read_link').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('.group_box').hide();
      return false;
    });
 });
</script>
```

ps $(self) makes no sense. Use $(this) for the current element

Answer (score 0):

onYou something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $().ready(function() {
     $("body").on('click','.mark_as_read', function() {
         $(this).closest('.group_box').hide();
        return false;
      });
   });
```

Instead use On ,bind is deprecated