# Hide headings that are displayed before the results of a filtered search

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a search filter code which should only show the value of the search, and this is working. It works perfectly with the jquery code below, but the problem is that it still shows all the headings.

What I want is for it to show only the heading of the word which is searched, and the rest should be hidden. How can I do this?

There are many classes between the `h2` and the search word. How can I tackle just the specific heading that belongs to the specific span with the class "einzeln" which contains the search word?
Could this task be solved by using the css classes "d_show" and "d_none"?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 

  $("#btn-click").click(function(event) {
    var toCheck = $('#inputfeld').val().trim();
    $(".einzeln").hide().filter(':contains(' + toCheck + ')').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.d_show{
    display: "";
}

.d_none{
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Beginner</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>I am just a text</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="inputfeld" stype="text" name="">
        <button id="btn-click" type="button">Click me </button>
    </form>
    
    <div id="mutter">
        <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
    <div class="alle sec_a">
        <span class="einzeln"> Anne </span>
        <span class="einzeln"> Amad </span>
        <span class="einzeln"> Albert  </span>
    
    </div>
        <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
    <div class="alle sec_b">
        <span class="einzeln"> Beat </span>
        <span class="einzeln"> Boris </span>
        <span class="einzeln"> Benny </span>
    
    </div>
        <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
    <div class="alle sec_c">
        <span class="einzeln"> China </span>
        <span class="einzeln"> Cees </span>
        <span class="einzeln"> Casa </span>
    
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome, you cannot apply `display: ""` that does not mean anything for it. And when you select `$('.class')` classes this way, you are getting all classes, I would recommand you to use .each to filter then directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide parent div by class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342814/hide-parent-div-by-class-name)

Comment: side note, :contains is case sensitive, so 'an' will not match 'Anne' Is that intentionally? Otherwise there are some filter/plugin options to search in another way

Answer (score 1):

We can do this quite easily by getting the container with the searched word (which you were already doing) and then finding the h2 heading that comes before it.

Your button is in a div that follows the heading, so this means you can find and show the word and the correct heading with just the following 2 lines in your click handler:

```
$(".h_title").hide();
$(".einzeln").hide().filter(':contains('+toCheck+')').show() 
             .parent('div').prev('h2').show();
```

**How this works:**

- Hides all titles: `$(".h_title").hide();`
- Hides all words: `$(".einzeln").hide()`
- ...finds and shows the searched word: `.filter(':contains(' + toCheck + ')').show()`
- ...then finds the parent div of the searched word: `.parent('div')`
- ...and gets the previous `h2` element  (i.e. the one before the searched word): `.prev('h2')`
- ...and shows it.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn-click").click(function(event) {
    var toCheck = $('#inputfeld').val().trim();
    $(".h_title").hide();
    $(".einzeln").hide().filter(':contains(' + toCheck + ')').show().parent('div').prev('h2').show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>I am just a text</h1>
<form>
  <input id="inputfeld" stype="text" name="">
  <button id="btn-click" type="button">Click me </button>
</form>

<div id="mutter">
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2 for A</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_a">
    <span class="einzeln"> Anne </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Amad </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Albert  </span>
  </div>

  <h2 class="h_title"> H2 for B</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_b">
    <span class="einzeln"> Beat </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Boris </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Benny </span>
  </div>

  <h2 class="h_title"> H2 for C</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_c">
    <span class="einzeln"> China </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Cees </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Casa </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @noobie this answer works in exactly the same way as your existing code, with the addition of finding the preceding `h2` element, so I'm pretty sure it should work in the scenario you described under one of the other answers. Can you try it and let us know if you need something different to what you described?

Comment: upvoted. For the record @noobie, if you want the search to be case insensitive you can use something like
   $("#btn-click").click(function(event) {
    const toCheck = $('#inputfeld').val().trim(),
       rx = new RegExp(toCheck,'i');
    $(".h_title").hide();
    $(".einzeln").hide().filter((i,el) => rx.test($(el).text())).show().parent('div').prev('.h_title').show();
  });

Answer (score 0):

Adding/removing classes is beneficial, but only when it makes multiple changes. However, here you just want to hide/show elements. So, I would prefer the use of `hide()` and `show()`, over adding/removing `classes`.

Besides that, the code you posted would hide all the elements in case it does not find any matching element. I have resolved that as well. Now it will not hide any element, in case the searched element is not found.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn-click").click(function(event) {
    var toCheck = $('#inputfeld').val().trim();
    var found = $('.einzeln:contains(' + toCheck + ')');
    var all = $('.h_title, .einzeln');
    
    all.show();
    if (found.length) {
      all.hide().filter(found.add(found.parent().prev())).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>I am just a text</h1>
<form>
  <input id="inputfeld" stype="text" name="">
  <button id="btn-click" type="button">Click me </button>
</form>

<div id="mutter">
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_a">
    <span class="einzeln"> Anne </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Amad </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Albert  </span>
  </div>
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_b">
    <span class="einzeln"> Beat </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Boris </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Benny </span>
  </div>
  <h2 class="h_title"> H2</h2>
  <div class="alle sec_c">
    <span class="einzeln"> China </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Cees </span>
    <span class="einzeln"> Casa </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,

first of all thanks for helping me out. in this contexts it works. But to be honest it is a visual composer code I am using and there are many classes between the h2 and the search word. How can I tackle just the specific h3, which contains the spicific span with the class "einzeln", which contains the search word?

Comment: @noobie If you have additional information or requirements, please edit your question to include them so that everyone can see them. Information in comments can often be missed. Can you also clarify the problem, because you are referring to `h3` elements that you haven't included in you question, and you also mention that they "contain" the span?

Comment: @noobie Please share the HTML structure what you are talking about. Besides that, please let me know if you want all the elements to hide in case the search does not match any element.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/5ntjqkyL/1/
Remove your css and replace js with:

JS:`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-click").click(function (event) {
        var toCheck = $('#inputfeld').val().trim();
        if (toCheck == "") {
            $(".h_title, .alle").show();
        }
        $(".h_title").each(function () {
            $(this).next(".alle").children(".einzeln").each(function () {
                if ($(this).html().trim() == toCheck) {
                    $(".h_title, .alle").hide();
                    $(this).parent(".alle").prev(".h_title").show();
                }
            })
        })
    });
});
```

`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out guys. I don't have the html structure because it was a teamproject made with visual composer. No I don' have access to that project anymore.

but guys rellay: thank you for you kind help!!!